# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sin\lfloor x\rfloor}x$

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

What does the following limit evaluate to?
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sin\lfloor x\rfloor}x$$
I know that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$$ but how to evaluate the above given limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin\lfloor 0-h\rfloor}{0-h}$$                           where $h>0$

## $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin\lfloor -h\rfloor}{-h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(-1)}{-h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-0.8414709848}{-h}$$(for -1 radian)

Please note that it is not an indeterminate form.Hence the limit doesnot exist.

---

By definition

> In mathematics, a limit is the value that a function or sequence "approaches" as the input or index approaches **some value**.

Infinity is not that **some value**.

Comment: it's +infinite as i said before.

Answer (score 1):

if $x$ is near 0 by right,  then $\lfloor x \rfloor=0$ and $f(x)=0$ so limit by right is zero (0).

if $x$ is near 0 by left, then  $\lfloor x \rfloor=-1$ and $f(x)=-1/x$, so limit by left is $+\infty$.

Thus the limit at 0 doesn't exist.

Comment: But I am asking limit x tending to $0^{-}$

Comment: it's  sin(-1)/0^-=+ infinity.